# Create datasets based on authors from another dataset

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataset in the following format

```
       text          author        title 
     -------------------------------------

dt =   text0         author0       title0
       text1         author1       title1
         .             .              .
         .             .              .
         .             .              .
```

and I would like to create different separate datasets which contain only texts of one author. For example the dataset names dt1 contains the texts of the author1, the dt2 contains texts of the author2, etc.

I would be grateful if you could help me with this using python.

**Update:**

```
dt = 
            text                                     author        title
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   I would like to go to the beach                   George       Beach
1   I was in park few days ago                        Nick         Park
2   I would like to go in uni                         Peter        University
3   I have be in the airport at 8                     Maria        Airport
```

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing what type of object your data is currently stored in, the expected output, and _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research, so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: @G. Anderson, sure, give me a second.

Comment: @G. Anderson, Please let me know if you need something more.

Comment: What is `dt`? A numpy array, a pandas dataframe, a single string with whitespace included, a text file, etc.? What have you tried to solve this yourself, and what issues, errors, or wrong outputs occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, this is what I understand you require.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'text' : ['text0', 'text1', 'text2'],
    'author': ['author0', 'author1', 'author1'],
    'title': ['Comunicación', 'Administración', 'Ventas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df["author"]=="author0"]

df2 = df[df["author"]=="author1"]
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Update:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'text' : ['text0', 'text1', 'text2'],
    'author': ['author0', 'author1', 'author1'],
    'title': ['Comunicación', 'Administración', 'Ventas']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df["author"]=="author0"]

df2 = df[df["author"]=="author1"]

list_author = df['author'].unique().tolist()

for x in list_author:
  a = df[df["author"]==x]
  print(a)
```

Comment: If you need something more dynamic include in a list the unique values of the author column and in a loop go through the list replacing the value after the '=='.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is what I was looking, one more question. In case that I would like to generalize this I was thinking to do the following ``` for name in authors_list:
  dt_str(name) = dt[dt["author"]=="name"]``` where the ``` dt_str(name)```  is not working. Is it possible to update your code?

Comment: I left you a small example, it can be improved a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I didn't make clear probably what I want. Is there any way to create names of data frames based on authors? For example the data frame dfauthor0 contains the texts of author0, etc. In your case you have used df1 and df1 manually and not automatically, if there any way to create dataframes with names of authors inside of the 'for' loop?